# P4Merge in the language of Subversion

Tags: perforce

When I use the app P4Merge I am very confused by its language. What are 'base', 'source', 'target' and 'merged'?

How do they correspond to the language used in Subversion? It uses the names 'base', 'theirs', 'mine' and 'merged'

Answer (score 0):

Try this description of the merge UI: http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4v/merging_files.html